# create an element based on the button you select

Tags: javascript, createelement

i want a button to create an element ("img") based on buttons they selected. for example i have a sweet and sour option. if they click the sweet option, and then click the submit button an image pops up but if they click the sour button and then click the submit button a different img pops up. heres what i have so far.

```
    <html>
    <div id='prefPage'>
    <header id='header2pref'>
    <div id='title2pref'>PREFERENCES</div>
    </header>

    <div id='body'>
    <div id='leftAlign'>



    <div id='drinkImg'><img src='logomain.png'></div>
    </div>

    <button id='myBtn2' onmousedown="mouseDownclear2()" onmouseup="mouseUpclear2()">SET PREFRENCES</button>


        <button id='buyBut' onmousedown="mouseDownclear()" onmouseup="mouseUpclear()">CLEAR PREFRENCES</button>


     <div id='rightAlignPref'>

     <div id=fixed>
     <div id="liqpicloc">



       </div>

        <div>
        <button id="button1">SWEET</button>
        <button id="button2">SOUR</button>
        </div>

        <div>
        <button id="button3">WEAK </button>
        <button id="button4">STRONG</button>
        </div>

        <div>
        <button id="button5">CHEAP</button>
        <button id="button6">PRICEY</button>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>


  </div>
  </div>
  </html>


    var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
    var pref = document.getElementById("myBtn2");    
    var liqpic = document.getElementById("liqpicloc");
    var liqpicloc = document.getElementById("liqpicloc");



    if(button1.style.backgroundColor = "FCCE08"){

          }  


    pref.addEventListener("click", function () {

        var liqpic = document.createElement("img");
        liqpic.src = "vodka.svg" ;
        liqpicloc.appendChild(liqpic);



   if(button2.style.backgroundColor = "FCCE08"){

          }  


    pref.addEventListener("click", function () {

        var liqpic = document.createElement("img");
        liqpic.src = "scotch.svg" ;
        liqpicloc.appendChild(liqpic);




    });
```

Comment: Getting any errors in this? if yes, please share your error

Comment: yes, regardless of which button i select both images appear when i click the submit button

Comment: Share your HTML code also

Comment: You're missing some brackets. Did you really mean to put the second `addEventListener` inside the first one?

Comment: You're missing the closing brackets of the first `pref.addEventListener() call.

Comment: added that, still doesn't do the trick. both images appear regardless of what button i select. they even appear if i dont select any button and then hit the submit button. im sorry i have so much code for this its hard to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have event listeners on the `SWEET` and `SOUR` buttons that set a variable, and then the listener on the `SET PREFERENCES` button should use that variable.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var pref = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
var liqpic = document.getElementById("liqpic");

var liqpicurl;

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  liqpicurl = 'vodka.jpg';
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  liqpicurl = 'scotch.jpg';
});

pref.addEventListener('click', function() {
  liqpic.src = liqpicurl;
  liqpic.alt = liqpicurl;
})
```

```html
<button id='myBtn2'>SET PREFRENCES</button>
<button id='buyBut'>CLEAR PREFRENCES</button>

<div id='rightAlignPref'>

  <div id=fixed>
    <div id="liqpicloc">
      <img id="liqpic">
    </div>

    <div>
      <button id="button1">SWEET</button>
      <button id="button2">SOUR</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button id="button3">WEAK </button>
      <button id="button4">STRONG</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button id="button5">CHEAP</button>
      <button id="button6">PRICEY</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```